# Replacing a word in a pandas dataframe that appears in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe of book information
I want to remove the title of the book from the description (e.g. here I want to remove the words 'The', 'Brooklyn' 'Bridge' when they appear, I have been struggling to fit other pieces of code to this problem. I know that other questions answer but none of the solutions given under those posts seem to give me the output I want.

```
Title                           Description
The Brooklyn Bridge     Describes the construction of the Brooklyn Bri...

print(df['title']
print(df['Description']
```

```
The Brooklyn Bridge
Describes the construction of the Brooklyn Bridge, from its conception by John Roebling in 1852 through its final completion under the direction of his son, Washington, in 1883.
```

```
df['Description'].replace(to_replace=r'\b'+df['title']+r'\b', value='',regex=True)
```

I've tried this and this

```
for strings in df['Description']:
    for word in df['title']:
            if word == strings:
                strings.replace(word, ' ')
```

but neither seems to get the result I want, as shown below

```
print(df['title'])            
print(df['Description'])
```

```
The Brooklyn Bridge
Describes the construction of the , from its conception by John Roebling in 1852 through its final completion under the direction of his son, Washington, in 1883.
```

```
Every time I try different code it doesn't come up with an error but it also doesn't remove the words I want it to.

I have more than a thousand books that I want to do this with so I can't use regex to each name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done without a loop.

You nearly had it in your for loop, but doing `strings.replace(word, ' ')` does not amend the dataframe, it just creates a copy of that string and then replaces the substring in that copy. To amend a dataframe in place use `.loc`

```
for idx in df.index:
    # locate row and column and set it to new value
    df.loc[idx, 'Description'] = df.loc[idx, 'Description'].replace(df.loc[idx, 'title'], "")
```